# If $k$ is the smallest integer such that $[a^k]>[a]^k$, which of the following is true?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

This is a question from the KVPY(SX)-2014 (an examination to get into various research institutes in India) paper.

> **Q.** For a real number $r$ let $[r]$ denote the largest integer less than or equal to $r$. Let $a > 1$ be a real number which is not an integer and let $k$ be the smallest positive integer such that $[a^k] > [a]^k$. Then which of the following statements is always true?
>
> $(A)\,\, k\le 2([a]+1)^2\quad (B) \,\, k\le ([a]+1)^4\quad (C)\,\, k\le 2^{[a]+1}\quad (D)\,\, k\le\frac{1}{a-[a]}+1$

The solutions which I’ve looked through on the Internet and on the booklet I’ve been given mostly state that by taking different values of a and k, option B is possible ( e.g.  [here](https://www.sarthaks.com/349392/for-a-real-number-r-let-r-denote-the-largest-integer-less-than-or-equal-to-r)). But have not provided a proof on why. Or have put forward a proof that doesn't click my head (e.g. [this](https://www.meritnation.com/ask-answer/question/for-a-real-number-r-let-r-denote-the-largest-integer-less-th/integrals/9714389)).

I'm looking for a proof that suits the needs for a 12th grader in India.

Comment: I changed the title after you changed the body of the question. In case you haven't seen this before, have a look at [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting math correctly here.

Answer (score 5):

You can argue for (D) by ruling out (A), (B), and (C), on the basis that they depend only on $[a]$, and not $[a]-a$. Any bound on $k$ depending only on $[a]$ can be defeated by choosing $a-[a]$ small enough. This kind of reasoning is quick and may be valuable on a timed test.

To see why (D) works (this part is unnecessary to answer the multiple choice question, but is a good sanity check if there is time), write $a = n+r$, where $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $0 < r < 1$. Put $k = \lceil 1/r \rceil$. We must show $(n+r)^k - n^k \ge 1$. By the binomial theorem,
$$
(n+r)^k - n^k = \sum_{i=1}^k \binom{k}{i} r^i n^{k-i} \ge k r n^{k-1} \ge n^{k-1} \ge 1
$$

Comment: I like this, quite elegant. A small supplement which helped me see the first paragraph more clearly: working with the binomial sum it is straightforward to argue that $ (n+r)^k - n^k < r(n+1)^k$, and if $k$ depends only on $n$, then one can clearly make this smaller than $1$ by sending $r$ to $0$.

Comment: I like that argument, as it gives us quantitative info as well. I had in mind just the trivial $x\mapsto x^k$ is continuous, so for any $n$, there is $\delta>0$ so that $(n+\delta)^k-n^k <1/2$, say.

Comment: In fact, it is nearly tight - noting that $k > 1$ is necessary, and assuming it, from the expression in your answer, $k > 1 + \frac{\log 1/r}{\log n}$ works. But from the above comment, $k > \frac{\log 1/r}{\log(n+1)}$ is necessary. This nails down the order of growth of $k$ as $r \to 0$ and $n \to \infty$.

Comment: The above isn't additively tight, though, because the gap is (roughly) $1 + \frac{\log(1/r)}{n \log^2 n}$ which can blow up. I wonder if this can be characterised simply.

Comment: Nice solutions....

Comment: @vujazzman Why did you put $k = \lceil 1/r \rceil$? Did you take using option?

Comment: @vujazzman Also 
$
(n+r)^k - n^k = \sum_{i=1}^k \binom{k}{i} r^i n^{k-i} > k r n^{k-1}=n^{k-1} >1
$??

Answer (score 0):

Update: Note the answer below is for the earlier version of the post's question, i.e., $[ak] \gt [a]k$. As requested by the OP, and I agree, I'm leaving it here for anybody who's interested.

Let

$$a = n + r, \; n \in \mathbb{N}, \; n \ge 1, \; r \in \mathbb{R}, \; 0 \lt r \lt 1 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Note $0 \lt r$ since it's stated $a$ is not an integer. Thus,

$$\lfloor a \rfloor = n, \; r = a - \lfloor a \rfloor \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Have $k$ be a positive integer where

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\lfloor ak \rfloor & \gt \lfloor a \rfloor k \\
\lfloor (n+r)k \rfloor & \gt nk \\
\lfloor nk + rk \rfloor & \gt nk \\
nk + \lfloor rk \rfloor & \gt nk \\
\lfloor rk \rfloor & \gt 0 \\
rk & \ge 1 \\
(a - \lfloor a \rfloor)k & \ge 1 \\
k & \ge \frac{1}{a - \lfloor a \rfloor}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

The *smallest* $k$ would be the [ceiling function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) (i.e., $\lceil \; \rceil$, which designates the smallest integer greater than or equal to the value) of the right hand side, which would be at most up to just less than $1$ more than the value, i.e.,

$$k = \left\lceil \frac{1}{a - \lfloor a \rfloor} \right\rceil \lt \frac{1}{a - \lfloor a \rfloor} + 1 \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Thus, option (D) is the correct one as always being true, although as shown above you can actually replace the $\le$ with the slightly more strict $\lt$.

Comment: Not sure on how this same to be. But I think somebody made a mistake on my question while editing. Anyhow, I corrected it but I think you should let this answer be, is very interesting to know how one small misprint brought up an entire option!

Comment: To make it clearer, here's the edited part: $[a^K]>[a]^k$

Comment: @ShreyasJV Thanks for letting me know.  I didn't check your post's question text matched what the linked ones stated.  As you've suggested, I'm leaving my answer anyway, but to help anybody reading it avoid confusion, I've updated it to state I'm answering something different than what is currently written.